# Копирующий конструктор и обработка исключений

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Возникла проблема при написании копирующего класса. Основной объект и его копия имеют общий адрес памяти. Как их разделить, при этом сохранить значение и в основном объекте, и в его копии? Вот, собственно, сам код. По завершению работы программа выдаёт ошибку как на скрине. Также пробовал добавить обработку исключений. Подчеркивает все `BadIndex`ы. Как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class INT
{
public:
    INT(unsigned _x, unsigned _y);
    INT(INT &I) :x(I.x), y(I.y), data(new int[x* y]) { data = &(I.data[1,2]); };
    int& operator () (unsigned _x, unsigned _y);
    int operator () (unsigned _x, unsigned _y) const;
    ~INT();
private:
    unsigned x, y;
    int *data;
};
inline INT::INT(unsigned _x, unsigned _y): x(_x), y(_y)
{   
    if (x == 0 || y == 0)
      throw BadIndex("Массив имеет нулевой размер");
    data = new int[_x* _y];
}
inline INT::~INT()
{
    delete[] data;
}
inline int& INT::operator() (unsigned _x, unsigned _y)
{
    if (_x >= x || _y >= y)
      throw BadIndex("Выбранный элемент находится вне массива");
    return data[x*_x + _y];
}
inline int INT::operator() (unsigned _x, unsigned _y) const
{
    if (_x >= x || _y >= y)
      throw BadIndex("Выбранный элемент находится вне массива");
    return data[x*_x + _y];
}
int main()
{
    INT a(10, 10);
    cin >> a(1,2);
    INT b(a);
    cout << "RESULT" << endl;
    cout << a(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << b(1, 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: пример ошибки]

Comment: Эм, а как можно иметь один адрес и разные значения? Похоже что нужна техника [COW](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш конструктор копирования неправильный. Вы пишете вот что:

```
INT(INT &I) :
    x(I.x), // скопировать значение х
    y(I.y), // скопировать значение y
    data(new int[x * y]) // завести новый массив data нужного размера
{
    data = &(I.data[1,2]);
    // Оппаньки! Затереть указатель на выделенный массив,
    // и прописать в него указатель на кусок старых данных
};
```

В результате в деструкторе `data` удалится дважды.

Это грубая ошибка, не делайте так. Судя по всему, вам просто нужно скопировать данные. Вы можете использовать, например, `std::copy_n`:

```
{
    // data = &(I.data[1,2]); // <-- неправильно
    std::copy_n(I.data, x * y, data);
}
```

Для Visual Studio вам придётся поизвращаться, так как стандартные функции там считаются недостаточно безопасными. Следующий трюк [должен сработать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985928%28v=vs.120%29.aspx):

```
std::copy_n(I.data, x * y, stdext::checked_array_iterator<int*>(data, x * y));
```

Никакая обработка исключений не нужна. Пишите код правильно, а не пытайтесь подавить сообщения об ошибках.

---

Кстати, поскольку `I.data` — не многомерный массив, то в выражении `I.data[1,2]` срабатывает, судя по всему, [`operator ,`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: Ругается на copy:
Ошибка 1 error C4996: 'std::_Copy_n': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'

Comment: @desuev: А какая у вас версия Visual Studio?

Comment: Именно ошибка, а не warning? Впрочем, у меня во всех исходниках давно прописано `#if defined(_MSC_VER)  #pragma warning(disable : 4996)`...

Comment: @VladD Версия VS 2013. И именно ошибка.

Comment: @klopp: Возможно, в проекте прописано warnings as errors

Comment: @VladD Добавил `#if defined(_MSC_VER) #pragma warning(disable : 4996)` , но это не помогло. Странно.

Comment: @desuev: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @VladD Помогла добавление вашей строки в самое начало, до добавления библиотек. Всё работает, благодарю. :)

Comment: *строки в самое начало* - ага, у меня это самый общий заголовочный файл, который включается во все проекты до любого другого. Для `_MSC_VER` там ещё несколько подобных "мелочей" прописано, но это уже на любителя.

Comment: @desuev: Попробуйте всё же как в обновлённом ответе, должно быть правильнее. Убирать предупреждения не всегда хорошо, можно случайно допустить ошибку.

Comment: @VladD На обновленный вариант тоже ругается, но теперь на stdext и <int>. Единственный рабочий вариант - с добавлением тех строк.

Comment: @desuev: А как ругается? Вы на забыли `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: @desuev: ... и наверное ещё `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: @VladD Вот `#include <iterator>`а не хватало. Теперь всё прекрасно работает. :)

Comment: @desuev: Отлично, вот и разобрались. Используйте или этот метод, или так, как предложил @klopp (с `#pragma warning`). Лучше посоветоваться с руководителем проекта по поводу того, как он считает правильно.

Comment: У меня отключено потому что основные инструменты - g++/gcc + cppcheck + valgrind, в студию этот код попадает нечасто :)

Comment: @klopp и VladD, Спасибо вам за помощь !

Comment: @desuev: пожалуйста!